# 52/36 Chainrings for Ultegra 6750 crankset

Tags: chainring, compact-crankset

I have standard compact (50/34) crankset. It seems to be to small for finish on flat stages. I am going to replace chainrings for semi-compact.
I've found that absoluteBlack offers products for older crankset like mine
[Premium Oval 110 4bolts](http://absoluteblack.cc/oval-road-110-5-bcd-shifting-chainring/)

- Do you know if there are any other chainrings (52/36) for 110BCD 5 bolt which fits Ultegra 6750 ?

Comment: Just buy a new Chainset its cheaper. A new 11 speed 52/36 works perfectly with Ultegra 6750, speaking from experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are. Any 110BCD 5 bolt chainring except Campagnolo will fit. If you want to keep the smooth appearance with hidden chainring bolts, at least Specialites TA and Stronglight make compatible chainrings at wide range of sizes.